# External functions from standard libraries are unresolved in lli

Tags: llvm, lli

I am trying to run simple code in llvm lli (according to [Getting Started with the LLVM System](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#id34))

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I got the .bc file with

```
clang –O3 –emit-llvm hello.c –c –o hello.bc
```

and

```
 lli hello.bc
```

but getting the next error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_printf' which could not be resolved!
```

I think it is very basic error, but I didn't understand what I did wrong.
working on windows.